# What to study first to create a Chatroom?

Tags: programming-languages, chatroom

What are some languages I should study to create a Chatroom?

Comment: The language is not the key issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programming language doesn't matter; you can create a chatroom in any programming language. What you probably want to know about is the [Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP)](http://xmpp.org/), how t perform network communication in the language of your choice, and any libraries that might help such as [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) if you want to integrate with any of the standard IM protocols.

Comment: Okay thanks, I heard that there are a lot of security risks when trying to make a chatroom. Can you please list some and what I should avoid?

Answer (score 0):

[IRC (Internet Relay Chat)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) is probably what you need.